# Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Using: CF10

I'm storing the key value of a struct in a variable as such:

```
<cfset ApplicationArea = '1'>
```

I want to find if this value exists in a struct like such:

```
StructKeyExists(SESSION.Auth.AccessA, #ApplicationArea#)
```

This all works. However, within the struct of `SESSION.Auth.AccessA["1"]` are further keys. I now need to find if a certain key exists in this struct. This is what I came up with but does not work:

```
StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.AccessA[#ApplicationArea#], '3') GT 0
```

I get the error of "**Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.**"

I want to know if the value of `'3'` exists in the struct of `SESSION.Auth.AccessA["1"]` (which it does when I dump the `SESSION` variable). I might have got my explanation confused slightly but I think its correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
if (ArrayLen(StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.AccessA[ApplicationArea], '3', 'ALL'))) {
    // it exists
} else {
    // it does not
}
</cfscript>
```

**EDIT:** non-cfscript as requested

```
<cfif ArrayLen(StructFindValue(SESSION.Auth.AccessA[ApplicationArea], '3', 'ALL'))>
    <!--- it exists --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- it does not --->
</cfif>
```

StructFindValue returns an array of structures containing information about the keys that match the value.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/StructFindValue

You don't need any of the `#` chars in your question (I know you asked about when and when not to use them recently)

Comment: Can you translate this without using <cfscript> please?

Comment: Dude, it is an if statement.  I think thats pretty straightforward.

Comment: All set, but seriously, asking for help is one thing, asking for others to write your code for you is not the point of this site.  Next time try reading the docs for the function you're using first.  It clearly states it returns an array.  Hence the "complex object cannot be converted to simple value" error.  An array can never be compared to zero as you showed in your question.

Comment: on a side note, i'm confused why it doesn't need the number signs. because i'm asking it to evaluate ApplicationArea and replace it with the correct value. How does it know that I'm not asking it to look in a struct key named 'ApplicationArea' ?

Comment: Typically your only need the `#` if you are using it in a string. So if you're doing struct["#varname#"] then yes you need them but you can just do struct[varname]. Sometimes you HAVE to use the quotes, say for example, a tag argument `<cfquery name="q" datasource="#application.dsn#">` in this case, you are in a string, so if you don't have the `#` then it will try to use a DSN called "application.dsn" when you really want the value. It was all clearly answered in your question yesterday. I suggest you take the time to read the responses, and the links that were suggested.

Comment: There are other exceptions like inside a cfquery, cfmail, etc, but those really are "strings" as well, you are sending a SQL string to the DB, or to the mail processor.  If you don't use a `#` it won't know that you want to evaluate that variable.  In CF statements, it assumes you want to evaluate the variable, so they are unnecessary in cfsets, cfif statements, function arguments, etc.  Again, read the responses to your questions and the links those folks suggested.  You'll find you don't need the `#` nearly as often as you might think.

Comment: I've been trying this out Sean and its not working for some reason. I'm posting a new question because it maybe something to do with strings in CF10